# Are questions about finding clothes seen in movie on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Tonight I was watching an episode of Suits and one of the character was wearing a beautiful neck tie and it got me thinking: are questions regarding clothing in movies or TV Series on-topic here? What brand it might be, where to buy it and similar?

In short:

#### Are question regarding how and where to buy clothing seen in a movie or TV series on-topic on this stack exchange?

Comment: Why the -1? I'd love a reason and perhaps notes on how to improve it enough to remove it.

Comment: It's no so much about improvement, it's a good and interesting question. But on meta votes are meant to express agreement/disagreement and if understanding your meta question as being in favor of such questions, that disagreement vote is meant as another indication, in addition to answering and voting on the answers.

Comment: Don't take it personally, as Napoleon Wilson said, [voting is different on meta](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). It's a good question, the downvote just means "I don't think it is a good idea".

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I thought that the here, like on the regular SE, votes were meant indicate whether or not the question was perceived to be a good one and/or met the qualitative standards of SE. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for asking!

The purpose of the site is to ask and answer questions about the content and the making Movies and TV shows.  A question about 'costume' in general would not be off topic if it added to an appreciation of the show - for example understanding that a movie might dress someone in a Saville Row suit to emphasize that they are English and rich perhaps.

However 'trivia' that doesn't really add much to the appreciation of the show - e.g. identifying a suit, is generally considered off topic.  This is especially so in the case of purchasing questions - as this information goes out of date as stock changes or retailers come and go.  Its not even on topic here to point people to where people can locate and buy movies themselves.

TL;DR : So in short I believe this would not be on-topic here.

Comment: I think this has been discussed before during that iron man question about that magnetic device.